# Windows analog of kill process with PID

Tags: windows, cmd, pid

One perfect blogger showed how to stop "wheel of death" when programm doesn't respond. It allows you to return to work and save data. This is a command: kill -SEGV -2034. Last digits are PID of process. This is a video where he describes how it works https://youtu.be/KnWhWVarfqM?t=473 (7 min 53 sec).
I dont have iMac, I use windows. My 2 questions are: 1) What does this command and its arguments do 2) What is analog of this command in Windows. I know how to find PID in Windows, but I cannot translate this command to cmd.exe.

Comment: `taskkill /?`. .

Answer (score 1):

Try TaskKill.

```
TASKKILL [/S system [/U username [/P [password]]]]
     { [/FI filter] [/PID processid | /IM imagename] } [/T] [/F]

Description:
    This tool is used to terminate tasks by process id (PID) or image name.
```

Answer (score 1):

To get list of running processes run **Tasklist** command,
Over there find the process you want to kill and remember it's PID.

Than you can kill the process with the following command, we will assume that process that we want to kill has PID of 2347 value.

Taskkill /f /PID **2347**

if you want to kill process by its name use /IM switch instead of /PID
Taskkill /f /im **chrome.exe**